# Hide Tor behind proxy?

Tags: socks, tails, whonix

I would like to set something like this Tor->proxy->webpage
I know I can use proxychains.
In Tails proxychains Tor Browser Bundle without setup proxy settings
In Whonix I can use it with Icewasel.

In whonix I can use Icewasel + Foxyproxy and add socks5 or http proxy and it will works without proxychains cause all will be torified through gateway and its working fine.

Is there a posibility to use ssh tunnel in Tails or in Whonix?
If I will bind ssh -D to localhost it will not work cause Tor is working 127.0.0.1 and these settings are in Web Browser.

What is best way to setup Tor->Proxy->Web in Whonix and in Tails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Whonix I can use it with Icewasel.

In Whonix you can use Tor Browser with a post-Tor-proxy (user -> Tor -> proxy) as well. ([documentation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnel_Proxy_or_SSH_or_VPN_through_Tor#Tunnel_SSH_through_Tor) [although in need of revision])

> Is there a posibility to use ssh tunnel in Tails or in Whonix?

Yes.

> If I will bind ssh -D to localhost it will not work cause tor is working 127.0.0.1 and these settings are in Web Browser.

In Whonix: you can change Tor Browser's proxy settings to your local ssh proxy.

> What is best way to setup Tor->Proxy->Web in Whonix and in Tails?

Depends on what you mean by "best". I will interpret it as "simplest". In Whonix: simplest is, set your proxy in Tor Browser's Tor Button proxy settings. ([documentation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnel_Proxy_or_SSH_or_VPN_through_Tor#Tunnel_proxy_through_Tor) [although in need of revision])

Comment: yeah great answer, please tell me more about tunnel in Tails